# Python Dell driver download

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href, urllib2

I have been trying my best to get all the dl for drivers using Beautifulsoup4. however it returns links I don't need. I think they are somehow hidden and for the life of me I can not get them out.

[here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/1h1c5p1/drivers) is the page I'm attempting to scrap: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/1h1c5p1/drivers

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
print link['href']
```

Comment: Which page do you really want to scrape? The dell one or the basecamp one?

Comment: Sorry about that I needed from the Dell site.  I Was working from command prompt window. That’s why my code was not readily available so I posted one of the examples I was working from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver links are loaded by js, so usually you'd have to use `selenium` or similar clients.  However in this case, all the driver info is available in json format, in a 'text/preloaded' script tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import json

resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/1h1c5p1/drivers")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser', from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='text/preloaded').text)

for item in data:
    print 'Name', item['driverName']
    print 'Link', item['fileFrmtInfo']['httpFileLocation']
```

Comment: Yes I think you’re right I remember reading about loading it with Java somehow. But it was late and I was racking my brain thought someone could help me out. Really appreciate the response I’ll try it tonight. Keep being awesome !

Comment: @JohnShiveley thanks, i'll do my best;) I would have posted a `selenium` solution, but i only use it as a last resort and this is doable with `urllib2`.